# Master/Detail filtering with a dropdownlist ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with selected value bound to a dropdownlist control. I was following [this](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/master-detail-filtering-with-a-dropdownlist-vb) so far I could manage to show some data if a user select a value from the dropdownlist but what I want is to show all records in '-- Choose a category --'

Here's the GetUser Method but what I want is C# version of it.

```
Public Function GetProductsByCategoryID(categoryID As Integer) _ As Northwind.ProductsDataTable 
  If categoryID < 0 Then 
    Return GetProducts() 
  Else 
    Return Adapter.GetProductsByCategoryID(categoryID) 
  End If 
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the same tutorial, but using C# rather than VB.NET

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/master-detail-filtering-with-a-dropdownlist-cs

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see the C# Tutorial links in the top page. I'm gettin old :S

Answer (score 1):

Did you try reading the [C# version of the tutorial](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/master-detail-filtering-with-a-dropdownlist-cs)?

Comment: Ah thanks I've seen it now. Also could you help me? How can I code behind it? I don't have a BLL so I connected it to the SQL server instead. I have a table 'category' with foreign keys from table 'books'. What I want is to display the whole records if dropdownlist is pointed to -- Choose a category -- just like in the tutorial but without the BLL.